# Quarkus apache kafka - can't disable health check

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, health-check

I am using Kafka ingoing message connector to accept messagges coming from a kafka topic. Sometimes error happen (sigh) and I would like to disable health check on this message connector only. I have tried many configurations but any can satisfy what I need to do.

This is the message connector (**ActionDlqConnector.java**):

```
 @NonBlocking
 @ActivateRequestContext
 @Incoming("actions-dlq-in")
 @Retry(maxRetries = 1, jitter = 1000L, delay = 2000L)
 @Acknowledgment(Acknowledgment.Strategy.PRE_PROCESSING)
 public Uni<Void> onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, ActionKafkaDTO> rejected) {
    log.info(String.format("Received dlq action: %s %s %s",
        rejected.topic(), rejected.partition(), rejected.offset()));
    return sessionFactory.withTransaction(session -> {
      log.info(String.format("Re-processing action: %s", rejected.value()));
      return service.processAction(rejected.value(), kafkaMessageTime(rejected), session)
          .onFailure()
          .invoke(e -> log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error saving action from dlq", e));
    });
  }
```

This my actual app configuration of this connector:

```
mp:
  messaging:
    outgoing:
      ...
    incoming:
      actions-dlq-in:
        topic: mytopic
        connector: smallrye-kafka
        failure-strategy: ignore
        consumer-rebalance-listener:
          name: consumer-seek.rebalancer
        health-readiness-enabled: false
        health-liveness-enabled: false
        health-enabled: false
```

Using this settings, when reaching `http://localhost:8080/q/health` (after the error happened) I still see:

```
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "checks": [
        {
            "name": "SmallRye Reactive Messaging - liveness check",
            "status": "DOWN",
            "data": {
                "application-com.mycompany.events.kafka.consumer.ActionDlqConnector#onMessage": "[KO] - No result found for query [FROM com.mycompany.events.model.Event WHERE eventKey = ?1]"
            }
        },
     ]
}
```

It seems that error is not *exactly* on the connector *actions-dlq-in* but it is that class connector.

I also checked on internet and found nothing that could fix this issues.

I need to keep the health status as UP even if an error occurs on that connector.

Comment: Hi, all I can think of is that the yaml configuration for `health-enabled: false` is not taken into account. Maybe you can try putting `consumer-seek.rebalancer` in quotes?

Comment: Hey @OzanGünalp, still not working. I have also tried to move `health-enabled: false` before everythingh else, still the same result :(

Comment: can you try using quarkus.reactive-messaging.health.enabled

Comment: I think the fact that you still get the failure propagated to the health check is because of `PRE_PROCESSING` on your method. If you remove that the failure strategy will be applied, which is ignore in your case. If you can't  `quarkus.reactive-messaging.health.enabled=false` is the way to remove all messaging related health checks.

Comment: Hey @JCompetence, i have tried `quarkus.reactive-messaging.health.enabled` but, as @Ozan Günalp suggested, it will disable ALL messaging related health checks. I still need the other health messages, so that solutions won't work for me. I will investigate in the PRE_PROCESSING tho. Thanks!